# xmlns:tools namespace attribute not reflecting in plugin Element

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I am developing a cordova plugin, my plugin code needs `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`namespace.
So, I added the same in Plugin.xml

```
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
id="com.sample.cordova"
version="1.0.0">
```

Now after adding the plugin to any cordova project, i don't see `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` namespace in Android manifest file.
It is like

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.sample.cordova" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

As per [cordova Plugin Specification](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification) it should add xmlns:tools namespace, but it is not happening. Any ideas how to achieve it

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem

Try to add in plugin.xml

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest" mode="merge">
    <manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" />
</edit-config>
```

it works for me.

Details [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

I've managed to solve it with the [cordova-custom-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config) in the following manner:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-manifest/@xmlns:tools" value="http://schemas.android.com/tools" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [cordova hooks](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html) for this problem, example code:

Your `hooks/android/manifest-hook.js`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');

module.exports = function (context) {
  const parseString = xml2js.parseString;
  const builder = new xml2js.Builder();
  const manifestPath = context.opts.projectRoot + '/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml';
  const androidManifest = fs.readFileSync(manifestPath).toString();

  let manifestRoot;

  if (androidManifest) {
    parseString(androidManifest, (err, manifest) => {
      if (err) return console.error(err);

      manifestRoot = manifest['manifest'];

      manifestRoot.$['xmlns:tools'] = 'http://schemas.android.com/tools';

      fs.writeFileSync(manifestPath, builder.buildObject(manifest));
      console.log("xmlns:tools added in AndroidManifest.xml");
    });
  }
};
```

and add code bellow  to ***plugin.xml***

```
<platform name="android">
  ...
  <hook type="after_prepare" src="hooks/android/manifest-hook.js"/>
  ...
</platform>
```