# how to set tools namespace with <edit-config> in android manifest

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

I haven't succeeded in setting the `tools` namespace on my Cordova app's manifest file. The correct way to do this is to use the [`<edit-config>` tag in the `config.xml`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config), like this:

```
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest">
            <manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" />
        </edit-config>
```

. I then use it to modify a `<uses-permission>` tag like this:

```
        <config-file parent="/manifest" target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" >
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="replace" />
        </config-file>
```

But I keep getting this error:

> The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:node" associated with an element type "uses-permission" is not bound.

Any ideas for how to do this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How did you solve this? I am currently facing this problem. Please help/provide exact steps on how did you solve the issue.

Comment: @sachinrathod someone suggested to me that `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` should be added to the `<widget>` of your `config.xml` file rather than using `<edit-config><manifest ...`. Sounds reasonable but I didn't try it out because I had already used xml2js to manually parse the manifest file and do what I wanted to do.

Comment: Could you please provide me with the steps on how did you solve the issue using xml2js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had little success with the built in functionality but good success with this plugin:
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config

> The purpose of this plugin is to enable manipulation of native platform configuration files that are not supported out-of-the-box by Cordova/Phonegap CLI.
> The plugin uses hook scripts to update iOS and Android platform configuration files based on custom data defined in config.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Add this text to the Widget tag at the top of your config.xml

i.e.

<widget id="com.mzbapps.serverlife" version="1.26.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" **xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"**>

Answer (score 1):

You can achive it without any external plugin:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest" mode="merge">
    <manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" />
</edit-config>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41243851/7138244

Works fine with cordova 11.